# AddRange throws StackOverflow Exception

Tags: entity-framework

I have 3 lists

```
List<Movie> movies;
List<Actor> actors;
List<Category> cates;
```

- `Movie` class has a property `List<Actor> main_actors` and a property `List<Category> in_cates`
- `Actor` class has a property `List<Movie> his_movies`
- `Category` class has a property `List<Movie> movies`

Now I have all these data and relations prepared, `movies.Count > 4000`, `actors.Count > 2000`, `cates.Count > 2000`

Then I use code like these to add them to the database

```
using(var ctx = new MovieContext()){
    ctx.Movie.AddRange(movies);
    //... add others.
}
```

Then I got a stackoverflow exception on the `AddRange` method. Anyone can help?